# Should I tell the interviewer I have a job offer from the competitor?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, negotiation

New grad here. Had a job offer from a startup tech company and about to interview another startup in a few days. Both startups are basically doing the same things (their office is in the same building as well) but the latter is better developed and has a huge sum of pre-seed funding.

In the interview, should I tell them that I currently have an offer from their competitor so I can leverage my potential salary? Or should I just tell them I have an offer? Which one is more professional and beneficial to me?

Answer (score 8):

**TL, DR:** Yes, it's worth disclosing that you have an offer from a competitor, but it may not be worth disclosing the competitor's compensation until the other company makes you an offer.

The main reason for disclosing that you have an offer is to let them know they need to make a decision quickly. Hiring processes can take weeks or even months. If you already have an offer from a competitor, the competitor probably expects your final decision soon, which may be well after the other company would normally reach their conclusion. By informing them that you have a competing offer, they will most likely either: accelerate their process if they consider you a promising candidate OR terminate your application process early. In either case, you should have the information you need to make the decision about the competitor in time.

The reason you should maybe NOT disclose the compensation is that compensation negotiation tends to be "anchored" at first number that is provided. That is, if you provide a compensation number first, they may then base their offer on that number whereas without that information, they may voluntarily give you a better offer. So, it's better to wait and see what they will offer you first. Then, if that is less than the other offer AND you feel like you would rather work for this company, you can use the other offer to see if they will meet or beat the offer.

Comment: I think it is a good way to negotiate. But what if they asked for the numbers, how should I reply?

Comment: @btp0769 There's plenty of advice out there for how to approach compensation discussions during the interview process. Usually it comes down to politely declining to provide a number and then pivot to either asking them about the compensation range they have in mind or asking them more details about the position they are offering. As a new graduate, it should be a bit easier to deflect this kind of question as you don't have current compensation for them to compare against. For example, you could say "I'm still doing my research on what a competitive salary is. Please give me your best offer."

Comment: @btp0769 with a non-answer: "Competitve, a rate that I'd be satisfied with".

Comment: I read the OP as also asking about the distinction between saying "hey Coca-Cola, I have an existing offer from Pepsi" vs saying "I have an offer _elsewhere_". As in, is it worth saying your offer is from a company operating in their space? Personally, I'm not sure that it is. Unless e.g. they're saying "Sure, `other company` may offer you $5k more money, but we have a great work-life balance. Have I shown you our cool foosball table?" — then it's probably worth letting them know you're comparing apples with apples as in, you're not comparing their start-up salary with CompuGlobalHyperMegaNet.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should I just tell them I have an offer? Which one is more professional and beneficial to me?

Just tell them you have an offer. That's both normal and beneficial. Telling them it's an offer from a competitor in the same building opens you to potential risks including missing out on both jobs.

You have no idea if they know each other, and naming companies in such a way can come back to bite you.